Unplanned user logout during PhpUnit test
I had a test environment that was working perfectly fine until every request needing authentication started to fail (functionnal tests, class extending webTestCase). I suspect it does so since adding a custom authenticator for specific API url but I cannot pinpoint where the problem happens. I use Symfony 5 and phpUnit 9.
What I see is that within my test file, the user session is properly setup. I use the Symfony LoginUser() method and before calling the request with the client, I can dump the session with the user and the security token's 'Authenticated' attributes is set to true. The User object is the one I used when all was working well, he has all the right Roles.
The request triggered after that fails, the exception caught is an " AccessDeniedException" (and the response is the login redirection planned by the application). Various dumps showed me that the running script never goes in the method tested indeed. In my AccessDeniedListener and in the support method of the custom Authenticator already mentioned, there is no longer a user in session or a security token. Also I can see this custom Authenticator in action, the entry_point in my security.yaml points at the usual form_login.
Here is a quick view of a simple test within my App :
protected function SetUp(): void {
    protected function SetUp(): void {    
        $this->client = static::createClient();
        $this->repository = static::getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository(Wipe::class);
        $this->userTarget = static::getContainer()->get(UserTestTarget::class);
        $this->security = static::getContainer()->get(Security::class);
    }

    /* Test the simple access to the wipe List Admin */
    public function testlistWipeAdmin(){

        $user = $this->userTarget->getTestUser('admin');
        $this->client->catchExceptions(false);
        $this->client->loginUser($user, 'admin');

        // dd($this->security->getUser());
        // $token = $this->client->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
        // dd($token->isAuthenticated(), $token->getUser()->getRoles()); 

        $this->client->request('POST', '/admin/app/wipe/list'); 
        //token = $this->client->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
        //dd($token->isAuthenticated(), $token->getUser()->getRoles()); 
        
        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    }
}

I do not find the precise point where the user is logged out and causes the problem. Have you ever encountered such behavior and do you have suggestions on how to debug this ?
